# Niceform js with Grails 1.3.7

Tags: javascript, css, grails, gsp

I'm going to use design from niceform css (http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/demo/v20/niceforms.html) ... in my web app. I'm using grails 1.3.7 at the moment.

I found that in the niceform.js it has a variable : var imagesPath = "../css/img/";

it seems I need to give the correct path in it, do you have any idea how to modify that path using grails ? I would like to able using dynamic links so it could : var imagesPath = "${grailsPath}/css/img/";

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would put the images into a niceform dir under Grails' images dir. Then put the .js code into a GSP template

```
<g:javascript>
  var imagesPath = "${resource(dir:'images/niceform')";

  // rest of JS code here
</g:javascript>
```

Assuming this template is named '_foo.gsp', use `<g:render template="foo"/>` where you would otherwise have included the .js file.

### Update

If you're using the new resources plugin (and you should be), use this instead:

```
<r:script>
  var imagesPath = "${resource(dir:'images/niceform')";

  // rest of JS code here
</r:script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts:

1. put niceform.js into your project and customize it (and rename to niceform.custom.js);
2. put your resources needed for niceform.js in *imagesPath*;
3. define global js variable *imagesPath* and use it in js files (see namespaces in javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Try resource like this: ${resource(dir:'css',file:'main.css')}